# Retrieve text from a file in ps script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a text file containing some data as follows:

```
test|wdthe$muce

check|muce6um#%
```

How can I check for a particular string like `test` and retrieve the text after the `|` symbol to a variable in a PowerShell script?
And also,
If Suppose there is variable $from=test@abc.com and how to search the file by splitting the text before "@" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be one possible solution

```
$filecontents = @'
test|wdthe$muce

check|muce6um#%
'@.split("`n")

# instead of the above, you would use this with the path of the file
# $filecontents = get-content 'c:\temp\file.txt'

$hash = @{}
$filecontents | ? {$_ -notmatch '^(?:\s+)?$'} | % {
    $split = $_.Split('|')
    $hash.Add($split[0], $split[1])
}
$result = [pscustomobject]$hash

$result

# and to get just what is inside 'test'
$result.test
```

*note: this may only work if there is only one of each line in the file. if you get an error, try this other method

```
$search = 'test'
$filecontents | ? {$_ -match "^$search\|"} | % {
    $_.split('|')[1]
}
```

Comment: Suppose there is variable $from=test@abc.com and how to search the file by spliting the text before "@" ? Thanks...!

Comment: `$prop = $from.split('@')[0]; $result.$prop`

Comment: The above solution worked in most of the cases but resulting out the following in some cases


Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key
 in dictionary: 'ExternalClient'  Key being added: 'ExternalClient'"
At D:\infiles\cust\mailx_ssl.ps1:19 char:14
+     $hash.Add <<<< ($split[0], $split[1])
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the text from the file.

```
$content = Get-Content "c:\temp\myfile.txt"
```

Then you want to grab the post-pipe portion of each matching line.

```
$postPipePortion = $content | Foreach-Object {$_.Substring($_.IndexOf("|") + 1)}
```

And because it's PowerShell you could also daisy-chain it together instead of using variables:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\myfile.txt" | Foreach-Object {$_.Substring($_.IndexOf("|") + 1)}
```

The above assumes that you happen to know every line will include a `|` character. If this is not the case, you need to select out only the lines that do have the character, like this:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\myfile.txt" | Select-String "|" | Foreach-Object {$_.Line.Substring($_.Line.IndexOf("|") + 1)}
```

(You need to use the `$_.Line` instead of just `$_` now because Select-String returns MatchInfo objects rather than strings.)

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
gc input.txt |? {$_ -match '^test'} |% { $_.split('|') | select -Index 1 }

or

sls '^test' -Path input.txt |% { $_.Line.Split('|') | select -Index 1 }

or 

sls '^test' input.txt |% { $_ -split '\|' | select -Ind 1 }

or

(gc input.txt).Where{$_ -match '^test'} -replace '.*\|'

or

# Borrowing @Anthony Stringer's answer shape, but different 
# code, and guessing names for what you're doing:

$users = @{}
Get-Content .\input.txt | ForEach { 
    if ($_ -match "(?<user>.*)\|(?<pwd>.*)") {
        $users[$matches.user]=$matches.pwd 
    }
}
$users = [pscustomobject]$users
```